# Replace words in a TextBox using Items of a ListBox as the source

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, listbox

I want to change the text in this TextBox:

[image: Source TextBox]

Using this ListBox as the of the words to change:

[image]

A word should be changed using the text inserted here:

[image]

I've already split the words into the `text[]` array.
Now, for example, when I select the word `who` and I click the `Replace` Button to replace `who` with `hey`: the string `who are you` should be changed in `hey are you`.
But it seems that my code doesn't work properly, it keeps showing the original text instead of the modified one:

```
private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string replace = txtReplace.Text;
    string tempReplace = "";
    txtList = listBox1.SelectedItems.ToString();
    txtText.Text = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i].ToLower() == txtList.ToLower())
        {
            text[i] = replace;
        }
        tempReplace += text[i] + " ";
    }
    txtText.Text = tempReplace;
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please edit your question to narrow down what "my code didn't work properly" means. It's unclear what's wrong here.

Comment: Note that `listBox1.SelectedItems.ToString()` will likely return `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection` rather than the value. Perhaps you wanted `.SelectedItem.ToString()`? I recommend having a nose through Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: oh i see thats why, thanks your method work perfectly

Comment: By the way, you can simply do `txtText.Text = txtText.Text.Replace(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), replace);`. This is _slightly_ different to your current method though, in that if your string was "test goodbye test", and you replaced "good" with "bad", you'd get "test badbye test". With your current method it wouldn't replace "good" in "goodbye". This alternative method may therefore not be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you Controls are *bound* together, in a combined effort to perform the same task, you could actually bind them to a common source of data and use data change notifications to update all these controls at the same time.

▶ The ListBox that lists the words in the source TextBox and the TextBox that modifies these parts can use the same source of data to create the Binding.

▶ The TextBox that provides the list of words can be updated when the data changes, using the [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse) event of the [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding) used to `connect` the TextBox that edits the parts of text to the source of data.
This is just one of the possible ways, more complex binding can be generated using these tools.

The source of data can be a `List<strings>` that contains all the words in the source text. But a simple `List<T>` alone cannot do much, so you can attach it to a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource): this class can provide data change notifications (so all Controls bound to this source of data are *informed* when the data changes).

You can setup the bindings after all Controls are ready to fully support data bindings (the `Form.Load` event can do) and create the source of data (the `List<string>`) when the source text is replaced.  In the visual sample, I'm using a Button for this, but it should be the occasion when the text in the source TextBox is replaced with another string. **Don't use its `TextChanged` event for this**.

```
private List<string> parts = null;
private BindingSource partsSource = null;

private void SomeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    partsSource = new BindingSource();
    partsSource.DataSource = typeof(List<string>);

    lstParts.DataSource = partsSource;

    var txtBinding = new Binding("Text", partsSource, "", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

    txtBinding.Parse += (o, args) => {
        if (parts.Count == 0) return;
        parts[lstParts.SelectedIndex] = args.Value.ToString();
        txtSource.Text = string.Join(" ", parts);
    };
    txtReplace.DataBindings.Add(txtBinding);
}

private void btnBind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parts = new List<string>(txtSource.Text.Split());
    partsSource.DataSource = parts;
}
```

**Visual results**:

→ The TextBox that provides the source text is named `txtSource`.
→ The Button is `btnBind`.
→ The ListBox is named `lstParts`.
→ The TextBox used to edit the parts is named `txtReplace`.

[image: DataBindings BindingSource Mixed Controls]